$L^{2}H_{0}^{1}$-estimate for solutions to the heat equation using the heat kernel
Let us consider the heat equation
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
u_t=u_{xx} & \text{in $\mathbb{R}\times (0,T)$}, \\
u(\cdot,0)=u_0 & \text{on $\mathbb{R}$}, \\
\lim_{|x|\to \infty}u(x,t)=0 & \text{for $t>0$}.
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
It is well known that when $u_0 \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$, we have
\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{T}\int_{\mathbb{R}}|u_x|^2 \ dx\ dt<\infty.
\end{equation}
This can be shown by a simple energy estimate. However, when trying to prove this using the heat kernel, I'm a bit confused. More concretely, with
\begin{equation}
g_t=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{4t}},
\end{equation}
we have $\partial_x u=(\partial_x g_t)*u_0$, and hence by Young's inequality,
\begin{equation}
\| \partial_x u \|_{L^2(\mathbb{R})}^{2}\leq \| \partial_x g_t \|_{L^1(\mathbb{R})}^{2}\| u_0 \|_{L^2(\mathbb{R})}^{2}.
\end{equation}
Now
\begin{equation}
\| \partial_x g_t \|_{L^1(\mathbb{R})}\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{|x|}{2t}e^{-\frac{x^2}{4t}}\, dx=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{\sqrt{t}|y|}{2t}e^{-\frac{y^2}{4}}\, \sqrt{t}dy\leq \frac{C}{\sqrt{t}},
\end{equation}
so we have
\begin{equation}
\int_{\epsilon}^{T}\int_{\mathbb{R}}|u_x|^2 \, dx\, dt\leq C^2 \| u_0 \|_{L^2(\mathbb{R})}^{2}\int_{\epsilon}^{T}\frac{dt}{t}.
\end{equation}
But the right-hand side is divergent in the limit $\epsilon \to 0$. I think I'm missing something. Can someone point that out for me?

[Thank you for your attention. I think I now have an answer so I will post it. Please give me feedback.]
Let
\begin{equation}
u_{0,n}(x)=F^{-1}\left[ \chi_{\{ 2^n \leq |\xi|\leq 2^{n+2} \}}F[u_0] \right](x) \quad (n\geq 0).
\end{equation}
Here, $F[f](\xi)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)e^{-i\xi x}\, dx$ is the Fourier transform (sorry "\mathcal{F}" is not rendered correctly on my Google Chrome so I use "F"), $\chi_S$ is the characteristic function of the set $S$, and $n$ is a non-negative interger. Let us denote by $u_n$ the solution to the heat equation with the initial data $u_{0,n}$. Then since
\begin{equation}
F[g_t](\xi)=e^{-\xi^2 t},
\end{equation}
we have
\begin{equation}
F[\partial_x u_n(t)](\xi)=i\xi e^{-\xi^2 t}F[u_{0,n}](\xi),
\end{equation}
and by Plancherel's theorem, we get
\begin{align}
\int_{\mathbb{R}}|\partial_x u_n(x,t)|^2 \, dx
& =\int_{2^n \leq |\xi|\leq 2^{n+1}}\xi^2 e^{-2\xi^2 t}|F[u_0]|^2 \, d\xi \\
& \leq 4^{n+1}e^{-2\cdot 4^{n}t}\int_{2^n \leq |\xi|\leq 2^{n+1}}|F[u_0]|^2 \, d\xi.
\end{align}
Now integrate this inequality from $t=0$ to $t=T$ to obtain
\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{T}\int_{\mathbb{R}}|\partial_x u_n(x,t)|^2 \, dx\, dt\leq 4^{n+1}\frac{1-e^{-2\cdot 4^n T}}{2\cdot 4^n}\int_{2^n \leq |\xi|\leq 2^{n+1}}|F[u_0]|^2 \, d\xi\leq 2\int_{2^n \leq |\xi|\leq 2^{n+1}}|F[u_0]|^2 \, d\xi.
\end{equation}
Similarly, let
\begin{equation}
u_{0,-1}(x)=F^{-1}\left[ \chi_{\{ 0 \leq |\xi|\leq 1 \}}F[u_0] \right](x)
\end{equation}
and let $u_{-1}$ be the corresponding solution to the heat equation. Then a similar calculation shows:
\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{T}\int_{\mathbb{R}}|\partial_x u_{-1}(x,t)|^2 \, dx\, dt\leq \int_{0\leq |\xi|\leq 1}|F[u_0]|^2 \, d\xi.
\end{equation}
Finally, taking the sum of the inequalities above, we conclude:
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{T}\int_{\mathbb{R}}|\partial_x u(x,t)|^2 \, dx\, dt
& =\sum_{n=-1}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{T}\int_{\mathbb{R}}|\partial_x u_n(x,t)|^2 \, dx\, dt \\
& \leq 2\int_{0\leq |\xi|\leq 1}|F[u_0]|^2 \, d\xi+2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\int_{2^n \leq |\xi|\leq 2^{n+1}}|F[u_0]|^2 \, d\xi \\
& =2\int_{\mathbb{R}}|u_0(x)|^2 \, dx.
\end{align}
Here, the equalities are due to Plancherel's theorem.
In this way, we can prove that $\int_{0}^{T}\int_{\mathbb{R}}|u_x|^2 \, dx\, dt<\infty$ without relying on the energy method. Furthermore, a simple modification yields not just $u\in L^2(0,T;\, H^1(\mathbb{R}))$ but also $u\in L^1(0,T;\, H^2(\mathbb{R}))$. I think the latter is difficult to prove using energy method alone.

I'd like to add some remarks on some intuition behind the calculations above.

For the initial data $u_0(x)=\chi_{\{ |x|\leq 1 \}}$, in the $O(t^{1/2})$ neighborhood of $x=0$ (as $t\to 0$), the derivative $u_x$ is $O(t^{-1/2})$; a similar estimate holds near $x=1$. So
\begin{equation}
\int_{\mathbb{R}}|u_x(x,t)|^2 \, dx=O(t^{1/2})O(t^{-1/2})^2=O(t^{-1/2}),
\end{equation}
which is integrable near $t=0$. Based on this example, we can see that a simple application of Young's inequality is too "global" to capture such phenomenon. So we must use more "localized" argument to be able to prove the desired finiteness; my answer is based on a localization argument in the Fourier domain.
The fact that a simple estimate gives $\| u_x(t) \|_{L^2(\mathbb{R})}^2=O(t^{-1})$ but it being integrable reminded me of a proof of Bernstein's theorem, which implies in particular that a $C^1$ periodic function has an absolutely convergent Fourier series (cf. [Chapter 3, Exercise 16; Stein & Shakarchi "Fourier Analysis"]); the proof uses the dyadic decomposition.
Using the Littlewood−Paley decomposition, we can prove analogous $L^p$-$L^q$ estimates of $u_x$; see [Section 3.4; Bahouri, Chemin, & Danchin "Fourier Analysis and Nonlinear Partial Differential Equations"].

